# difference between CoreBluetooth framework and IOBluetooth framework

Tags: xcode, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Whats the difference between CoreBluetooth framework and IOBluetooth framework (Used for MAC apps)?

Answer (score 6):

CoreBluetooth is an iOS framework for Bluetooth LE communication. 
IOBluetooth is an OS X framework for both Bluetooth Classic and Bluetooth LE. IOBluetooth contains the CoreBluetooth framework within it and uses most of the same code as the iOS version for Bluetooth LE on the desktop.

Comment: CoreBluetooth is available on MacOS X, iOS, AppleTV, and WatchOS. IOBluetooth is only on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

CoreBluetooth is for accessing Bluetooth Low Energy APIs.
and IOBluetooth is for Bluetooth Classic Interface

Comment: No CoreBluetooth is for LE

Comment: CoreBluetooth is just for LE but IOBluetooth can search for both